# Is it possible to use coldfusion with apache, and mysql?

Tags: coldfusion

Is it possible to use coldfusion with apache server  and mysql DB?

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely, yes.

See the [ACME guide](http://www.acidlabs.org/library/The_ACME_Guide_3rd_Edition.pdf) - Apache Coldfusion, MySQL, Eclipse

Comment: yep. I'm currently running CF9 on Apache and using CF Builder (based on Eclipse). I'm hitting SQL Server and Oracle databases, but could hit MySQL as well if I had it installed.

Answer (score 4):

i do not try but its seem  possible:

http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/coldfusion-8-and-apache-on-windows-xp-116

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is and it works fine. ColdFusion has a Apache Connector and can work with mysql as a datasource!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely work, I use it, but it does differ in ease of install based on windows vs linux. I have gotten it to work on windows, not sure about linux.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide I wrote for [installing the ACME stack on Linux](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/6/6/The-ACME-Guide-64bit-Ubuntu-804-Edition-Part-1).

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can run under apache and use mysql as well. 
I wrote blog about load balancing between two different of coldfusion but I have mention setting needs apply 
 http://www.thecfguy.com/post.cfm/load-balancing-with-apache-tomcat-on-coldfusion-standard-version